# How to test if a particular version of php executable is available on a server?

Tags: php, php5, automation, php53

An automatic upgrade Bash script requires PHP executable 5.3+, how do I ensure that is the case in the upgrade script?  I'd like the script to quit and generate some message into the log when php 5.3+ is not available.

Update:  the servers where I currently need this to work is Debian and in near future it'll be Ubuntu. Another assumption is that PHP are "standardly" installed.

Comment: I highly doubt there is going to be a generic answer to this if you don't limit your target system in some way.  Can you be assured that this is limited to a single Linux distro?  Can you assume the package was installed with the distro packaging system?  Are you certain the PHP CLI will be available, and not just the apache module?

Comment: Debian and possible Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php -r 'print_r(version_compare("5.3", phpversion()));'`

Comment: What if there is `/usr/local/php54/bin/php` but the default php is not linked to it?

Comment: @user213607 That contradicts your "another assumption" given in your question.

Comment: You mean if php is installed standardly there can't be a `/usr/local/php54/bin/php`?

Comment: That would not fall under the definition of 'standardly installed' for me.

Comment: `You mean if php is installed standardly` - Per Debian policy no official package can place files under `/usr/local`.  Someone could build a deb package that would drop files their, but you certainly will never see that on a package from the Official Debian/Ubuntu repos.